Windows 11 не видит свободное место на диске
Я использую SSD-диск ADATA на 4TB. 
Проверка диска говорит, что на нём 175 GB свободно

На диске всего одна папка, в которой 3.47TB (используется сжатие файлов), что с этим согласуется

При этом в меню на диске свободно всего 84GB
Индексирование средствами Windows отключено. Ранее я уже сталкивался с такой проблемой. Тогда она была вызвана сжатием файлов и исправилась командой проверки диска, однако теперь такой способ не работает. Система Windows 11.
